# What does this difference in score means?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I have built a Linear Regression Model, I am getting two different scores for Train and Validation set, What does this mean?
This is the result I got 
The score for Train Data:  0.8802644749581061
The Score for Validation Data:  0.7124061878004602

NOTE :- I have not used my Testset yet.

I built an ML model (Linear Regression) then I checked the score on Training part and Validation part:

```
reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
reg.score(X_train, y_train)
```

This is what is got from this line of code:

Train Data:  0.8802644749581061

Validation Data: 0.7124061878004602

Comment: Can you provide the code you wrote. It's hard to say anything without knowing what exactly you have done.

Comment: @thilakshiK I built an ML model (Linear Regression) then I checked the score on Training part and Validation part -, reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)......
reg.score(X_train, y_train)...This is what is got from this line of code- The score for Train Data: 0.8802644749581061.......And when i check Model's score on Validation part- this is what i got (Validation Data: 0.7124061878004602)

Comment: please do not add the code in the comments. Update the question with it.i'll do it for you here but for future questions, always add meaningful information to the core text of the questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AmitYadav   Validation data set is used to minimize over-fitting. If the score over the training data set increases, but the score over the validation data set stays the same or decreases, then you're over-fitting your linear regression model.

Comment: @Alexis Thank you very much, I still do not know how to put code there in question.

Comment: @thilakshiK Thank you very much. Yea, I figured it out. I am trying Lasso or ridge to fix this overfitting problem, But not able to get proper code. May you help me in getting it fixed (May you share some lines of code in Github if you have somewhere there?)

Comment: @AmitYadav  You can find how to reduce over-fitting by regularize through this link.  https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/04_training_linear_models.ipynb. If you want to check on that in more details please read the book written by the author. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/. (Chapter 4 under the topic Regularized Linear Models ) Hope you find it useful. The book is available for free download.

Answer (score 0):

From the [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) website, we can know that score:

> Returns the coefficient of determination R^2 of the prediction.
>
> The coefficient R^2 is defined as (1 - u/v), where u is the residual sum of squares ((y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum() and v is the total sum of squares ((y_true - y_true.mean()) ** 2).sum(). The best possible score is 1.0 and it can be negative (because the model can be arbitrarily worse). A constant model that always predicts the expected value of y, disregarding the input features, would get a R^2 score of 0.0.

In your case, the R^2 value of training data is higher than validation data which means the model is overfitting.

Comment: Thank you very much